# User can't access network drive from non-domain PC

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, samba

An employee that is using his own computer that is not joined to AD needs to access two domain shares, H: and U:.

All the permissions for both the folder on the server and the share itself are configured the same on both shares. When he logs in on an A.D joined PC the mounting is successful but on his PC he can only access one of them.

What should I check to troubleshoot the configuration?

I ensured the permissions are set up correctly. I ensured it is machine-based by trying to perform the same task on other non-AD machine, successfully.

Comment: You have a tag for SAMBA but do not mention it in your question.  Do you have *nix server that is doing some sharing in this situation?

Comment: @Citizen doesn't windows server Call it a smb share too?

Comment: The protocol is called SMB.  SaMBa is *nix module for sharing files as a windows server.

Comment: @Citizen Oh then... I really ment pure windows environment. Sorry for misleading

Comment: No problem, just making sure I understood.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that non-AD machine has SMB connectivity to server (Windows Firewall public profile settings for non-domain machines, third-party network firewall)?

Did you check also user name format when connecting to shared folder? It should contain domain name - DOMAIN\Username, in other case client would try to connect with local user credentials.

Comment: I did. The User can connect to the server's other shares but not this one...